# getting 500 server error while using Postman, Not able Authenticate Salesforce SOAP API Authentication - Login Request

Tags: soap-api, postman

I followed All steps properly but still getting response as 500 server error:

Response at Postman:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <soapenv:Fault>
            <faultcode>soapenv:Client</faultcode>
            <faultstring>The child of the Envelope element must be either a Header or Body element</faultstring>
        </soapenv:Fault>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

My Request code:
End Point URL : https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/49.0

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" > 
    <env:body>
            <n1:login xmlns:n1="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
            <n1:username>*****</n1:username>
            <n1:password>****</n1:password>
            </n1:login>
    </env:body>
</env:Envelope>
```

```
Content-Type : text/xml
SOAPAction : ''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you got specifies

> The child of the Envelope element must be either a Header or Body element

"body" and "Body" aren't the same, and based on you receiving that error, I'd say that capitalization matters in this context.

You should be using `<env:Body>` instead of `<env:body>` (and yes, proper capitalization needs to be observed with closing tags too)